# Change size of Intellisense box in Visual Studio 2022

Tags: visual-studio, intellisense, visual-studio-2022

After installing Visual Studio on a new System after having used 2019 for many years on my old one it seems the devs have changed quite a lot. First I needed to change the font to Consolas again back from the new Cascadia, but now I have reached a problem I cannot figure out:

I am using 133% zoom in VS as usual because I have a 1440p monitor. But while the font is correct now, the Intellisense box is now ridiculously large. This was not the case in 2019. What setting do I need to change to correct this behaviour again and make the box and the font smaller?

[image: Box]

Answer (score 0):

I can reproduce your issue:

[image]

The setting is here:

Tools – Options – Environment - Fonts and Colors > Statement Completion

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Acutally I have the same problem and fixed it with Tools –> Options –> Environment –> Fonts and Colors -> Editor Tooltip:

[image]

Much Better!!!

[image]